# Не пересобирается vue на сервере Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

На локалке все хорошо работает, вношу изменения во vue файле, используя команду `npm run dev`, получаю ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте все изменения появляются(на локалке)

Вношу изменения на сервере во vue файле, использую команду `npm run dev`, получаю ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте 0 изменений

Пробовал команды `npm run watch` и `npm run watch-poll`(После команды вносил изменения во vue) он пересобирался, но результатов на сайте 0

Не знаю куда копать, выручайте

На сервере стоит Ubuntu 16.04.4

Comment: у тебя в .env environment=production стоит?

Comment: @PaulWall Не стоит, на сколько я понимаю это, чтобы использовать разны env для под локал и сервер?

Comment: да, а из под какого пользователя запускаете?

Comment: @PaulWall У меня разные файлы .env я их не трогаю. Запускаю из под root

Comment: а если npm run prod ?

Comment: @PaulWall Не помогло, а в чем суть это команды? Размеры файлов уменьшилось, js 324 кб, css 155 кб

Comment: она минифицирует и вообще предназначена для живого сервера. На сервере node_modules то все нужные есть? как переносили на живой вообще?

Comment: Использую git, с локала на гит и с гита на сервер. В папка node_modules стоит в gitignore, на собирал отдельно, ставил все тоже, что и на локалке(express, ioredis, socket.io, socket.io-client)

Comment: а может просто не заниматься порнографией и собирать на локалке с npm run prod как и задумывалось? там на живом где-то определяется что это prod сервер, где не знаю, и поэтому не собирается (ну я так думаю) поэтому проще просто сделать правильно, чем пытаться решить это))

Comment: @PaulWall Проблема началась с того, что я сначала на локалке собирал командой `npm run dev` или `npm run watch-poll`, потом отправлял на сервер и на сервере не каких изменений не было, я подумал, что на сервере нужно отдельно пересобирать и по этому протестировал команду `npm run prod` на сервере. Сейчас сделал ее на локалке, все работает, на сервере появились изменения, большое спасибо

Comment: да ты по сути при разработке ставишь npm run watch-poll и перед коммитом делаешь npm run prod =)